# ProgressDialog doesn't show when uploading Image

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a class which is used for uploading images to the server.
While uploading I want to show a progressDialog to show the progress of the upload.
Yet somehow the Progressbar doesn't show up.
This is my ImageUploader class:

```
package com.OBO.Bandenanalyse;

//Imagine Imports here    

public class ImageUploader {
private Context context;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

public ImageUploader(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Uploading Image... Please wait!");
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

private static String serverResponseMessage = "";
private static int serverResponseCode = 0;

public int uploadFile(final String sourceFileUri, final String serverFile) {

    Debug.out("SourceFileUri: " + sourceFileUri);
    Debug.out("ServerFile: " + serverFile);
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String upLoadServerUri = serverFile;
            String fileName = sourceFileUri;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
                Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
            }
            try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                Debug.out("in the try");
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a
                                                                    // HTTP
                                                                    // connection
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // URL
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                Debug.out("Set Properties and Datastream");
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                Debug.out("Writes data");
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a
                                                                // buffer of
                                                                // maximum
                                                                // size

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                Debug.out("Buffer done");
                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Debug.out("Read Bytes");
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                Debug.out("After sendData");
                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
                Debug.out("Server Response: " + serverResponseCode);
                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
                Debug.out("HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage
                        + ": " + serverResponseCode);
                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();
                // Toast.makeText(UploadImageDemo.this,
                // "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(),
                        ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Toast.makeText(UploadImageDemo.this, "Exception : " +
                // e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

        }
    };
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
        Debug.out("done uploading");
        dialog.dismiss();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Debug.out("Message: " + serverResponseMessage.toString());
    return serverResponseCode;
}
```

}

I'm calling the function in an AsyncTask as i need to do other business aswell. I do that like this:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Mail, Integer, Double>{
    /**
     * Private boolean to check if a tire is repairable or not.</br>
     */
    boolean _repairable = Step4._isRepairable;

    /**
     * Private integer which counts how many times we've tried to send the Email.
     */
    private int _counter = 0;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(isPhotoTaken()){
            ImageUploader uploader = new ImageUploader(_context);
            uploader.uploadFile(getPhotoPath(), "http://obo.nl/android-upload-image.php");              
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method used to start {@link #postData(Mail)} on a background thread.
     * 
     * @return null
     */
    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(Mail... params) {
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Method used to send the mail through a JSON Request in combination with the website.
     * If there is no Internet connection the program will try to send the mail every 10 seconds.
     * 
     * @param valueIWantToSend
     */
    public void postData(Mail valueIWantToSend) {
        if(AppStatus.haveNetworkConnection(_context)){
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://obo.nl/android-mailing.php");
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", valueIWantToSend.getFrom()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", valueIWantToSend.getTo()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", valueIWantToSend.getSubject()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", valueIWantToSend.getBody()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("localized", getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName()));
                if(PathToPDF(_repairable).contains("Goed_Gekeurd_NL")){
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("outputResult", SERVER_BANDENANALYSE_GOED_GEKEURD_PATH));
                } else if(PathToPDF(_repairable).contains("Afgekeurd_NL")){
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("outputResult", SERVER_BANDENANALYSE_AFGEKEURD_PATH));
                } else if(PathToPDF(_repairable).contains("Goed_Gekeurd_FR")){
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("outputResult", SERVER_ANALYSEPNEUS_GOED_GEKEURD_PATH));
                } else if(PathToPDF(_repairable).contains("Afgekeurd_FR")){
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("outputResult", SERVER_ANALYSEPNEUS_AFGEKEURD_PATH));
                } else if(PathToPDF(_repairable).contains("Goed_Gekeurd_DE")){
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("outputResult", SERVER_REIFENANALYSE_GOED_GEKEURD_PATH));
                } else if(PathToPDF(_repairable).contains("Afgekeurd_DE")){
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("outputResult", SERVER_REIFENANALYSE_AFGEKEURD_PATH));
                } else if(PathToPDF(_repairable).contains("Goed_Gekeurd_EN")){
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("outputResult", SERVER_TYREANALYSE_GOED_GEKEURD_PATH));
                } else if(PathToPDF(_repairable).contains("Afgekeurd_EN")){
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("outputResult", SERVER_TYREANALYSE_AFGEKEURD_PATH));
                }
                if(isPhotoTaken()){
```

//                      ImageUploader uploader = new ImageUploader(_context);
//                      uploader.uploadFile(getPhotoPath(), "http://obo.nl/android-upload-image.php");
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", getPhotoPath()));
                    }
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

```
                //This is the response from a php application
                String reverseString = response;
                Log.i("info", reverseString);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
        } else {
            if(_counter == 0){
                _counter++;
                _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        Toast.makeText(_context, getString(R.string.noInternetEmailNotSend), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            postData(valueIWantToSend);
        }
    }

}
```

Furthermore _context is set like this in onCreate of the activity:

```
_context = this;
```

What happens in the PostData method is sending the mail, with the taken photo as attachment (but that's not intresting as that works quite well).

So how come the dialog doesn't show up?

Comment: Instead of creating dialog in constructor, you can create the dialog in `onPreExecute()` method and dismiss it in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Nopes i can't, which is too bad. This because it's only for uploading the image. While the Asynctask is used for sending an Email. (which needs to have the image be uploaded before attaching it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't start your thread in ImageUploader method. change your method to this:

```
public ImageUploader(Context ctx) {
this.context = ctx;
((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog..setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading Image... Please wait!");
        dialog.show();
    }
}).start();
}
```

Comment: Hmmm If i add .start(); It won't compile anymore saying: Cannot invoke Start() on primitive type void.

Comment: .start() is necessary because your Thread never start. maybe because you didn't set your ProgressDialog Style. I have edited my answer test it again.

Comment: Even with the style added to it it still doesn't work. Yet i'm convinced i should start the thread

Comment: whya did you use rubOnUiThread? what is the problem with normal Thread? beacause I used normal Thread for waiting user dialog and worked nice.

Comment: That's because it's an UI element, so technically it should run on the UI-thread, but let me try putting it on a normal thread.

Answer (score 0):

first, as you are creating object for ImageUpLoader in onPreExecute() of AsyncTask, you no need to specially invoke runOnUIThread() method in constructor as onPreExecute runs on UI Thread and for dialogue, try this...
remove thread.join() statement,

```
 Thread thread = new Thread() { 
 public void run() {
      // your upload code stuff here
      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
           public void run() {
             if(dialog.isShowing()) {
               dialog.dismiss();
             }
           }
      }
 }
```

when UI components are created in UI Thread, they need to be handled in UI Thread most probably. (trying to dismiss dialog in new Thread)

Comment: Hmmm This ain't going to work, as the tread.join is used to check if the thread finished uploading the image.